# What is this connector?

Tags: audio, connector, soldering

I'm working on soldering a 3.5 mm female jack to the Thinkgeek Personal Soundtrack Shirt Controller so I can output to any speaker I please, however I am wondering if this is an actual connector I can buy so as to not have to solder in the cable.  The connector in question is the white one in the left of the image.

[image]

Worth mentioning the fact that it did have the connector, but it was lost years ago thus leading to me now trying to make it into something <strike>useful</strike> fun.

Comment: Now how come you couldn't see for your self that the connector, the one part you are specifically asking about, is blown out in this photograph and not even properly in focus.  You wouldn't hand in a homework assignment or present this picture to a customer, so it doesn't belong here either.  We deserve the same level of respect.

Comment: It's the only photo I could find on the internet, as I don't have anything higher quality than an auto-focused 720p webcam.  I am aware its not of the best quality, but I have no better alternative at the time being.  EDIT: I don't have one to take a picture of either, that's the reason I need it identified.

Answer (score 4):

The connector is not something special, it's seen a lot in computers, and if you go to your local electronics store<sup>1</sup>, they probably have the male part. It's called a '2 Position 0.1 Inch Straight Friction Locking Header'. That is, it's a header, with...

- 2 Position -> there are two pins
- 0.1 Inch -> the distance between the pins
- Straight -> the pins are straight (that is, not bend)
- Friction lock -> the header as a locking system which prevents it from popping off

If I'm not mistaken, [here](http://www.digikey.com/short/7czm8b) is the male part.
(But I'm absolutely not sure! I would recommend you to buy this part in a local shop.)

I don't think there's a this-connector-to-jackplug part, so you will still have to solder a bit. However, if you use the male part, your connector is still intact, and you can still use it in your shirt as well.

By the way, see [here](http://www.whitearmor.net/forum/topic/23143-how-do-i-mod-a-thinkgeek-personal-soundtrack-shirt-to-output-to-aker-amp/) for a similar project.

<sup>1: I don't mean a hardware store, but an electronics parts store. If you don't have one nearby, you can also try in a shop dealing with computer components, and maybe they have something. If you're lucky, they have an old cable they wanted to throw away and you can get it for free!</sup>

Comment: Didn't expect a conversion to be available, but it's good to know the male part can probably be purchased.  I had come across that forum in my searching but I hadn't found any references to the part by name.  Thanks!

Comment: @LawsontheJedi no problem & happy to help - but please don't accept the answer to quickly. Other users may have something else to say. Please wait a day (or two) and then see which answer is the best.

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Comment: @VladimirCravero Because the question was 'What is this connector?' and not 'Where can I buy this connector?'

Comment: -1 as it's not a header. There is some additional locking details which means it's not a standard header, though I'm not familiar enough with every locking 2-pin connector to name it exactly.

Comment: @PeteKirkham you're right, thank you. I didn't look carefully enough. I updated the name.

Comment: @CamilStaps  I suspect that your ID of the male part may be in error.

Comment: The male header half-in-question is a housed keyed header... and the connector fully in question is a matching keyed connector.

Answer (score 1):

That's a connector commonly called "JST HR" but not always manufactured by JST Manufacturing nor the HR-style pin pitch. You will find it on eBay under that name though. Measuring the pin pitch will tell you whether you should look for "JST HR 2.5" (2.5mm), "JST HR 2.0" (2.0mm), or some other pitch.